# The light signal path through the light clock

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, time-dilation

Light clock: floor, ceiling, light signal
Case 1: when light colck is in rest, light signal propagates straight up.
The time the light signal needs to pass the distance floor-ceiling-floor is t
Case 2: when light colck is moving, light signal propagates obliquely, one says.
The time the light signal needs to pass the distance floor-ceiling-floor is t' = tγ, where γ is the Lorentz factor.

I consider that case 2 and the following calculations are incorrect.

A light signal moves at a constant speed c and with the same
 direction regardless of how the light source moves.

What causes the light signal goes obliquely in case 2?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Jan Slowak! I do urge you to search this site before posting a question to see if your question (or a similar one) has already been asked and has answers here. We do expect that some basic research, including searching this site, has been done before posting a question here. I've voted to close your question as a duplicate and I have also downvoted because your question does not show any research effort. You might find [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) helpful

Answer (score 1):

> What causes the light signal goes obliquely in case 2?

The laws of electromagnetism. This is easiest to understand using some simple geometry and ray optics. Suppose, for example, that the device producing the beam of light consists of a spherical light source with a pinhole.

In the rest frame of the device the spherical source emits a pulse which is all absorbed except for the ray going vertically through the pinhole. In a frame where the device is moving all of the light is absorbed except for the ray going obliquely through the pinhole.

So the same ray which is vertical in one frame is oblique in the other frame, just by following the standard rules of light.